# Photos & Optimise Mac Storage

Tags: icloud, photos, disk-space

I always kept all the photos on my laptop. Now my space is getting low and I decided to switch to "Optimise Mac Storage"

[image]

How can I *trigger* the optimisation?

The disk is full

```
Filesystem   Size   Used  Avail Capacity   iused  ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1  699Gi  695Gi  2.9Gi   100% 182360388 765264  100%   /
```

but the size of the Photos library is not changing. Opening and closing Photos does not seem to change anything. Keeping Photos open for a long time does also not bring any effect.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? Most likely the process simply hasn't checked, and restarting photos wouldn't change that because photos has background processes that handle some things.

Comment: @EzekielElin Yes nothing happens after a reboot